# Conditional probability with complementary events

Tags: probability

I have a little (or to you really easy) question concerning the conditional probability. Suppose now we have two events F and S (not sure whether they are dependent or independent), and we know the probability of P(F), P(S) and P(F|S). Assume further that the complementary event of F is ~F (as such we know the probability of P(~F) ), then how should we get the probability P(~F|S)? I think shouldn't be something like "1-P(F|S)" but don't know how to derive it...?

(there's no other information available, I need to compute P(S|~F) by getting the value of P(~F|S) and so didn't see any solution to get P(~F|S) )

Thanks a lot when I'm really having problem with understanding every little thing!

Answer (score 0):

Try to prove that $P(F \mid S) + P( \neg F \mid S) = 1$.

Hint: $F \cap S$ and $(\neg F) \cap S$ are mutually exclusive, and 
their union is $S$.